# how can i compare the selected values with the existing one in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-generation

I have a view like this,

```
<% count = 1 %>
<% for voting in @voting %>
    <% if voting.question_id.eql?(count) %>
        <%= radio_button( count, voting.vote_count, :radio_id => voting.nominees  ) %>
        <%= voting.nominees %> 
    <% end  %>

    <% if voting.nominees.eql?(radio_id) %>
        <% voting.update_attribute('vote_count', voting.vote_count+1 ) %>
    <% end  %>
    <% count += 1 %>
<% end  %>
```

how can i compare the selected nominees with the existing one.

any help on this would be very useful...

Comment: sorry, no idea what the code should do. Is the selected in the db or what?

Comment: Yea, it's difficult to offer much help without knowledge of what each of these variables are, or what the code is trying to do. Can you elaborate at all? What is contained in the @voting variable?

Answer (score 1):

Some models and associations would be handy here. I suspect [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M001627) will be your best friend.  Also look at [increment](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M002338).